# Task Scheduler - Windows 10

Tags: windows-task-scheduler

I am trying to use task scheduler on Windows 10 to run shutdown.exe after idle for 2 hours. When I set it up, it will work for 10 minutes instead of 2 hours, if I try 30 minutes of idle time it still runs at 10 minutes.

I use the /r argument.

I was told by another user that it cannot run past 1 hour of idle time then was told it was a bug issue. So my question is, am I doing something wrong, or are my settings wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Is the task scheduler you're after or is it putting computer into sleep?

Comment: How do you let to know scheduler that your computer is idle anyways?

Comment: No, it's logging out the user after 2 hours of idle time. That's what we want it to do. As far as letting the scheduler know, it's part of the settings when creating a task.

Comment: Still don't get it. If you want to put into sleep then use power settings, if you have some external mechanism to start scheduler then, by curiosity, how it goes, and two, why don't you do that using that mechanism rather than scheduler?

Comment: You are as well off to use the Windows Power functions and let it suspend after two hours. Shut it down when necessary. That will work better.

Comment: Agreed with everyone else on using the windows power stuff instead of "rolling your own".  It sounds like the power stuff is probably what is kicking in at 10 minutes anyway.  An idle timer that won't go past an hour sounds like hogwash to me.  The OS relies on idle timers to do all sorts of things.

Comment: We are not looking to put the computer to sleep. Just to have the session log off after the user is idle for more than 2 hours. I figured using the task scheduler would work.

Comment: @JessicaMcDonald - You can have a user's session automatically lock after a period of time.  Why are you looking to logoff the user instead of just locking the user's session?

Comment: Your question says shutdown, and your comments say sign out. Please use the EDIT button to make your question more clear.